# How to use array.find() with typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

With the following code I get an error that the find() property not exist:

```
var foobar = [];
var bar = { value: 123 };
var foo = { value: 456 };
foobar.push(foo, bar);
console.log(foobar.find((obj) => obj.value === 123));
```

If I use the same code with javascript it works without problems.

Edit: Maybe a bit dirty workaround... You can cast foobar to any and so dodge the compiler error: 
console.log( **(foobar as any)**.find((obj) => obj.value === 123));

Comment: [It works fine for me](https://repl.it/repls/AquamarineWindingJavascript).

Comment: yihaaa, thanks for a delayed downvote with a so detailed reason -.-

Comment: I didn't downvote, nor voted to close this --_--.

Comment: Upvote, because I searched for it and found here the solution. Please do not downvote without delivering a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, all code should compile to plain JavaScript, so your code should work. If it doesn't for whatever reason, try TypeScript's `filter()` method instead of `find()`:

```
foobar.filter(obj => obj.value === 123)[0];
```

Comment: `filter` requires iterating over every item, `find` doesn't.

Comment: @jhpratt Using a loop is a simple and painless solution.

Comment: I dont know why the compiler was unhappy with find() but filter() works as expected - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've checked this code. All works fine.

```
const bar = { value: 123 };
const foo = { value: 456 };
const foobar = [foo, bar];

console.log(foobar.find((obj) => obj.value === 123));
```

Comment: The code works, but does TS recognise the results type?

Comment: If type of array and searched item are the same, why not? Set array and item types directly. const arr: Array<number> = ..., const searchedItem: number = ... Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What is giving you the error? Is it your browser, your text editor, or the Typescript compiler?

If it's your browser, you need to change the `target` in your `tsconfig.json`. Try `es5`. [Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Node 0.12](https://node.green/) don't support `Array.find`.

If it's your text editor, you need to fix the editor settings. Which setting exactly will depend on the editor. You'll want to find the setting for your Javascript or Typescript language version and set it to `es6` or above.

If it's the Typescript compiler... I don't actually know what could cause that. Perhaps a very old version of Typescript?

Comment: VS2017 compiler throw the error. Not sure if its a bug but I use now .filter() and it works.